# Ruby - confirming data and sending to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is not really a coding question, it is more about the approach. I am new to Ruby, but know several other languages.
The idea is the following:
I have a list of art classes, and the users can register to those classes (one-to-many)
I created Users and ArtClasses models.

I also created Registrations model, which holds the cross-reference between the user and the class he subscribed to.

Basically, everything currently works already up to the last screen, where I have all the information about the class and the user - ID, email, and the rest.

My question is: What is the best approach to confirm the subscription and send the data to the database table (registrations model)? Should it be the form with non-editable fields and "Submit" button, or is there any more elegant solution? Again, this is about the approach.
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the details you provided I believe it'll be better if you don't show any confirmation screen at all. In my opinion confirmation screens should be displayed when there is something important and potentially 'dangerous' happening, like payments.

So, unless this subscription is something the user can't edit later, I suggest you don't display any confirmation screen.

Comment: Actually, on that screen I also check if the user is logged in, and if not - redirect to login or register. So you suggest that the "Register" button will update the database directly? Thanks

Comment: You can use a `before_action` on your controller to check if the user is signed in and redirect to the route you want if not.